# Activity as a intent receiver to just start another and quit

Tags: android, android-activity

My app can be called from different intents, specifically from Android TV. I have created a special activity for this with the proper intent filter in the manifest. (If that intent (TV) were starting the main activity gave problems, with a specific activity works well)

My question is, that TVActivity just starts the main activity in onCreate() and should stop as it has no further use. Calling finish in onCreate() or onStart() seems a bad idea. What would be a clean and safe way to kill this activity and leave the other running?

Comment: You can call `finish()` in `onCreate()` if all you are doing is starting another `Activity`. However, I don't understand why you need a separate `Activity` if all it does is start another `Activity`. Please explain the problems you were having when `MainActivity` was started directly from Android TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that i got your question right, but you can see common usage of SplashActivity :

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {       
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                WeekplanHepler.isLoggedIn(SplashActivity.this);
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, YourActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
```

As you see, it's finished just before starting another because we no longer need it, so, if you have similar situation, it's ok to do finish whenever new activity starts